# How to obtain a part of the source from an imagesource string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call a part of the src of an image in a javascript function. How to go about it?

On the HTML page there is this image whose source is a imagepath from the database. I am trying to just extract this imagepath from the image src into the src of my javascript function.

this is the image :

```
 <img id="Image4" alt="" style='height: 200px; width:120px' src='<%# ResizeTransform(Eval("image_path").ToString(),120,200) %>' class="thumbnailimg" />
```

the js code is as :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnailimg').on('click', function () {
                var img = $('<img />', {
                //src: this.src,
                src: this.src("image_path"),
                'class': 'rs'

            });

            $('.img-container').html(img).show();
         });
      });
    </script>
```

how do i just extract the "image_path" from the image src into the src of js function?
currently its not displaying the image when i use :  src: this.src("image_path") and a blurred image when i use :src: this.src.

Comment: What is the meaning of blurred image? are you able to show image or not

Comment: you can do with simply set attribute -  $("img").attr('src',yoursourcepath);

Comment: actually the HTML line i shared is for a thumbnail image. But the thumbnailimg click function is to populate another image whre i want to show the expanded image.

Comment: No. the source path is not set.. it will change dynamically.

Comment: that understood. so the thumb image, you are able to set, now concern is you want to get another image when click. so that image(big) path are you set in the existing image object or get from url.

Comment: what we did in our project for the same logic you want to implement is : we store total 5 images with different-2 dimention of the same image   while upload images. Now in the project everywhere show the thumb, but when click we open a popup with big images. for this we created the name of 5 images with abbreviation like 1.jpb is main image, so small image will be 1_s.jpb, bigimage will be 1_b.jpg. We just replace the name dynamically while showing the big image in the popup.

Comment: Yes. i am able to display the image even with src: this.src, but the issue is that it gives a blurred image, bcoz the image4 src is a resized version of the image path in db. I actually want to call the original image. which is 720* 1020

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192465/discussion-between-ajay2707-and-anita-mathew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `let src = $(this).attr('src');` to get src attribute.

Update: the problem may come from ResizeTransform function.

You should add attribute `data-original='<%# Eval("image_path").ToString() %>'` to your img tag and get data by `let src = $(this).data("original");`

If can not use data-original use try `srcset='<%# Eval("image_path").ToString() %>'` and get data by `let src = $(this).data("srcset");`

```js
//data-original=<%=Eval("image_path").ToString()%>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnailimg').on('click', function () {
        //let src = $(this).attr('src');
        //let src = $(this).data("original");
        let src = $(this).attr("srcset");
        //alert(src);
        var img = $('<img />', {
            //src: this.src,
            src: src,

            'class': 'rs'


        });


        $('.img-container').html(img).show();
});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="Image4" srcset='https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/social-media-image-sizes-2019-min.png' data-original='https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/social-media-image-sizes-2019-min.png' alt="" style='height: 60px; width:120px' src='https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/social-media-image-sizes-2019-min.png' class="thumbnailimg" />


<div class="img-container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! i am able to display the image even with src: this.src, but the issue is that it gives a blurred image, bcoz the image4 src is a resized version of the image path in db. I actually want to call the original image. which is 720* 1020

Comment: I change img src, if the original imge hase 720*1020 size, it will show that size?

Comment: with this code i am getting a image with same size as thumbnail..But I want zoomed vs of that image..720*1020

Comment: but original image is thumb?

Comment: no original image is 720*1020, the path of which is stored in db and is being called in src='<%# ResizeTransform(Eval("image_path"). But on selection of paticuar thumbnail I want the original dimensions  of that image.

Comment: I updated answer, you can add an attribute on img tag

Comment: says data-original not a valid attribute of img.

Comment: dont worry that warning, i add custom attribute, it still run in my demo source code

Comment: That would not be possible ..these images are in a image carousel. and thumbnail click is for selecting particular image form the many in carousel. I tried your code but its not populating the slected image thumbnail.

Comment: updated answer, use srcset attribute instead of data-original

Comment: its not happening..i need to place src= '<%# Eval("image_path").ToString() %>' or srcset='https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/social-media-image-sizes-2019-min.png' and where to place the <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. hwen i place it after : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jcarousel/0.2.8/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script> its messing the carousel.

Comment: @ Hien Nguyen, I am getting this error on the console in devoper mode : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/xyz/image/200001_03.jpg

Comment: you need run in your web server, because browser not allow CORS for local file. also if answer is helpful, you can vote it up, thanks :)

Comment: Ok . got it , though it is fetching the image paths in the srcset .

Comment: home.aspx?class=1:513 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jcarousel is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home.aspx?class=1:513)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.A (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ home.aspx?class=1:513
l @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
A  does this make sense?

Comment: did you include jcarousel in your script? if you can share your source code somewhere, i will take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192551/discussion-between-anita-mathew-and-hien-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `attr('src')` to get the source if the image

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnailimg').on('click', function () {
         $('.img-container').html('<img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"> ') 

        });
 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="Image4" alt="" style='height: 60px; width:120px' src='https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png' class="thumbnailimg" />


<div class="img-container"></div>
```

Comment: with this code i am getting a image with same size as thumbnail..But I want zoomed vs of that image..720*1020

Answer (score 0):

For this just set a custom property in image object in the design while render, later you just get that property in jquery :

```
cust-imgpath='<%# Eval("image_path") %>' // add this in image tag

//in jquery, you will get property on click function 
$("img").attr('cust-imgpath');
```

The js code look like is as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnailimg').on('click', function() {

    var img = $('<img />', {
      //src: this.src,
      src: this.attr('cust-imgpath'), //here you get the custom attribute value 
      'class': 'rs'
    });
    $('.img-container').html(img).show();
  });
});
</script>
```